# convert numpy string array into int array

Tags: python, numpy

---

I have a numpy.ndarray

```
a = [['-0.99' '' '0.56' ..., '0.56' '-2.02' '-0.96']]
```

how to convert it to int?

output :

```
a = [[-0.99 0.0 0.56 ..., 0.56 -2.02 -0.96]]
```

I want 0.0 in place of blank ''

Comment: try `a.astye(float)`. Bear in mind, that a must be a numpy array.

Comment: it says AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'astye'

Comment: It is `astype` and that is what you're looking for

Comment: NumPy uses `array`s. Not sure what you mean by a NumPy list ...

Comment: That's a float array, and you want `a.astype(np.float)`.

Comment: it is not duplicate. see question in detail. I have blank string as well.

Comment: int array? Those are floats.

Comment: if you are on Python 3, then it should np.array(a, dtype=np.float32)

Answer (score 16):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['-0.99', '', '0.56', '0.56', '-2.02', '-0.96']])
a[a == ''] = 0.0
a = a.astype(np.float)
```

Result is:

```
[[-0.99  0.    0.56  0.56 -2.02 -0.96]]
```

Your values are floats, not integers. It is not clear if you want a list of lists or a numpy array as your end result. You can easily get a list of lists like this:

```
a = a.tolist()
```

Result:

```
[[-0.99, 0.0, 0.56, 0.56, -2.02, -0.96]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a pure python solution and it produces a *`list`* .

With simple python operations, you can map inner list with float. That will convert all string elements to float and assign it as the zero indexed item of your list.

```
a = [['-0.99' , '0.56' , '0.56' , '0.56', '-2.02' , '-0.96']]

a[0] = map(float, a[0])

print a
[[-0.99, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, -2.02, -0.96]]
```

Update: Try the following

```
a = [['-0.99' , '0.56' , '0.56' , '0.56', '-2.02' , '-0.96', '', 'nan']]
for _position, _value in enumerate(a[0]):
    try:
        _new_value = float(_value)
    except ValueError:
        _new_value = 0.0
    a[0][_position] = _new_value

[[-0.99, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, -2.02, -0.96, 0.0, nan]]
```

It enumerates the objects in the list and try to parse them to `float`, if it fails, then replace it with `0.0`

Comment: Ok I update my answer and make it handle everything in your list. If it can not parse, then it will replace with `0.0`

Comment: It also preserves `nan` values.