# Python Regex: Proper way to extract separated numbers (AxBxC -> [A, B, C])

Tags: python, regex, string, extract

I am now trying to extract sizes from the string, which is a very common pattern i guess: AxBxC where A, B, C separated with x (may be x with spaces also), are the sizes (int or float):

```
import re

s = 'zzz 3062 0.2 aaa 15.8x20.2x12.2875 mm'
```

I am expecting to obtain onli three numbers: [15.8, 20.2, 12.2875]
The only working approach i have now is ugly:

```
r1 = re.findall('(\d+\.?\d*)\ *x\ *', s)
r2 = re.findall('\ *x\ *(\d+\.?\d*)', s)
r1.extend(r2)
print(set(r1))

{'15.8', '20.2', '12.2875'}
```

Is there any way to use single robust regexp for extraction these numbers? 
Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't `\d+\.*\d+` be enough? This should get any numbers separated by anything except a decimal point.

For you example it finds [3062, 0.2, 15.8, 20.2, 12.2875]

Comment: @Zinki No. It will get those `3062` and `0.2` too.

Comment: Maybe `re.findall(r'(\d[\d.]*)x(\d[\d.]*)x(\d[\d.]*)', s)`? These numbers always go in triples, don't they? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0K5v5P/1).

Comment: Yes, this is good, but what if we have AxB (only two dimensions)?

Comment: Make the 3rd one optional - [`r'(\d[\d.]*)x(\d[\d.]*)(?:x(\d[\d.]*))?'`](https://regex101.com/r/0K5v5P/2), it will return `('15.8', '20.2', '')`

Comment: Great (and amazing resource as well!) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to match 2 or 3 `x` separated float values. You may use

```
r'(\d[\d.]*)x(\d[\d.]*)(?:x(\d[\d.]*))?'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0K5v5P/2)

**Details**

- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Group 1: a digit and then 0+ digits or/and `.`
- `x` - a literal `x`
- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Group 2: a digit and then 0+ digits or/and `.`
- `(?:x(\d[\d.]*))?` - an optional sequence of `x(\d[\d.]*)`, an `x` followed with Group 3 capturing a digit and then 0+ digits or/and `.`.

In Python, use

```
re.findall(r'(\d[\d.]*)x(\d[\d.]*)(?:x(\d[\d.]*))?', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution if you don't know how many numbers you will have to get:

```
((?:\d+\.\d+)(?=x)|(?<=x)(?:\d+\.\d+))
```

It's based on the fact that or the x is before your number or after it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, for r1, you can use the following:

```
r1 = re.split( "x", re.findall('\d*\.\d*x\d*\.\d*x\d*\.\d*', s )[0] )
```

Unfortunately, it still exists of two commands, and by nesting this, it becomes a bit hard to read.
And if you want to use them as numbers, they should still be converted from string to a number, e.g. for each number `float(r1[#])` or use the numpy version to convert the whole array, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451776/convert-numpy-string-array-into-int-array).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
>>> s.split()[-2].split("x")
['15.8', '20.2', '12.2875']
```